# char* element of class is empty

Tags: c++, arrays, string, class

I am relatively new to C++ and classes. When I pass a char* through to the class constructor and copy it into the m_make and m_model char*'s, they are still empty. They are not pointing to random bits of memory when I print them out, no data is outputted, just blank space.
    Constructor:

```
RentalCar::RentalCar(int year, char * make, char * model, float price, bool available)
{
       m_year = year;
       myStringCopy(m_make, make);
       myStringCopy(m_model, model);
       m_price = price;
       m_available = available;
}
```

EDIT:

```
void readFile(RentalAgencyADT * list, ifstream & file)
{
char letter;
char word[7];
int i = 0; //position in word
int j = 0; //position in RentalCar data
int k = 0; //position of line in RentalAgencyADT
int l = 0; //position of RentalAgencyADT
while((letter = file.get()) != EOF)
{
    if(letter == ' ' || letter == '\n')
    {
        int year;
        char make[7], model[7];
        float price;
        bool available;
        i = 0;
        if(k != 0)
        {
            switch(j)
            {
                case 0:
                year = atoi(word);
                j++;

                break;
                case 1:
                myStringCopy(make,word);
                j++;
                break;
                case 2:
                myStringCopy(model,word);
                j++;
                break;
                case 3:
                price = atof(word);
                j++;
                break;
                case 4:

                available = (bool) atoi(word);
                list[l].inventory[k - 1] = RentalCar(year,make,model,price,available);
                j = 0;
                k++;
                break;
            }
            clearWord(word);
            i = 0;
            if(k == 7)
            {

            }
        }
        else if(k == 0)
        {

            switch(j)
            {
                case 0:
                myStringCopy(list[l].name, word);
                j++;
                break;
                case 1:
                //intCopy((list[l].zipcode),word);
                //cout << list[l].zipcode << endl;
                for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                {
                    list[l].zipcode[i] = word[i] - '0';
                    cout << list[l].zipcode[i];
                }
                j = 0;
                k++;
                break;
            }
            clearWord(word);
        }
        if(j == 4)
        {
            clearWord(make);
            clearWord(model);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        word[i] = letter;
        i++;
    }

}
```

}

Here is the RentalCar.cpp file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "RentalCar.h"
using namespace std;
   char* myStringCopy(char * destination, char * source);
   RentalCar::RentalCar(int year, char * make, char * model, float price, bool available)
   {
       m_year = year;
       myStringCopy(m_make, make);
       myStringCopy(m_model, model);
       m_price = price;
       m_available = available;
   }
   char* myStringCopy(char * destination, char * source) 
   {
       int i = 0;
       while(source[i] != '\0')
       {
           destination[i] = source[i];
           i++;
       }
       destination[i] = '\0';


       return destination;
   }
   int RentalCar:: getYear()
   {
       return m_year;
   }
   void RentalCar:: setYear(int year)
   {
       m_year = year;
   }
   char* RentalCar:: getMake()
   {
       return m_make;
   }
   void RentalCar:: setMake(char * make)
   {
       myStringCopy(m_make, make);
   }
   char* RentalCar:: getModel()
   {
       return m_model;   
   }
   void RentalCar:: setMode(char * model)
   {
       myStringCopy(m_model, model);
   }
   float RentalCar:: getPrice()
   {
       return m_price;
   }
   void RentalCar:: setPrice(int price)
   {
       m_price = price;
   }

   bool RentalCar:: getAvailable()
   {
       return m_available;
   }
   void RentalCar::setAvailable(bool available)
   {
       m_available = available;
   }
   void RentalCar::print()
   {
       cout << m_year << " " << m_make << " " << m_model << ", $" << m_price << ", Available: " << boolalpha << m_available << endl; 
   }
   float RentalCar::estimateCost(int days)
   {
       return m_price * days;
   }
```

I was using the strcpy() function earlier just to test but it didnt work either.

Headerfile:

```
#ifndef RENTALCAR_H_
#define RENTALCAR_H_
class RentalCar
{
public:
   RentalCar(const int year, char * make, char * model, const float price, bool available);

   int getYear();
   void setYear(int year);

   char* getMake();
   void setMake(char make[]);

   char* getModel();
   void setMode(char model[]);

   float getPrice();
   void setPrice(int price);

   bool getAvailable();
   void setAvailable(bool available);

   void print();

   float estimateCost(int days);

protected:

private:
    int m_year;
    char * m_make;
    char * m_model;
    float m_price;
    bool m_available;

};
#endif
```

Comment: Post all the code.

Comment: You probably have several problems here, almost all of which would go away if you used `std::string` instead. First, you have to allocate space for the chars - `strcpy` just copies, it doesn't make room for anything. Second, when you copy the car you need to allocate and create new copies of the characters again. And there is more, like destroying the strings. So if at all possible, use `std::string`.

Comment: Also, why are you using `char*` (and presumably, `char[]` as the member type), when `std::string` exists? You're writing C++ code, don't tie one hand behind your back. Odds are, your code will run slower using `char*`/`char[]` because *every* operation will need to recheck the length by scanning for the `NUL`, it will be less secure/stable (because it's easy to overflow buffers with stuff like `strcpy`), etc. Even in ideal circumstances, the "gains" to be had from C-style strings are trivial, and the added maintenance costs more than outweigh them.

Comment: i'm not allowed to use strings for the project

Comment: @BenNordin: Then you're going to need to post more of the class. Odds are you've errors with memory allocation, or buffer overflows, or something worse. We can't say what without a [MCVE].

Comment: Not allowed to use `std::string` but `std::fstream` is totally fine?  I mean, if they're gonna make you use C, you might as well go all in with `FILE*` etc.

Comment: @BenNordin: You posted the code that uses `RentalCar`, but not the  class definition, which  is important here. You also use a `myStringCopy` without defining it, and given copying seems to be a problem here, that's an important omission. Also, are all your makes and models guaranteed to be 6 characters or less? Your buffers won't hold any more than that.

Comment: @ShadowRanger: Yes, the makes and models are guaranteed to be 6 characters or less

Comment: Side-note: Pretty sure `(letter = file.get()) != EOF` is wrong. `letter` is declared as `char`, which will truncate anything larger like, say, `EOF`, which intentionally doesn't fit in the range of `char`; `ifstream.get()` returns an int-like type precisely to ensure `EOF` can be distinguished from all legal `char`s you could read. Also, technically, `EOF` is for C `stdio`, not C++ `iostream`, which would compare to `std::char_traits::eof()` I believe (though I wouldn't be surprised if the two values are the same on most implementations)

Comment: I don't even know where to begin. Which book are you using to learn C++?

Comment: @BenNordin: We need the attributes of `RentalCar`, which aren't defined in the `cpp` file, but in the header.

Comment: Re your edit, you were asked to post the class definition of `RentalCar`, and you still haven't done so. You are `strcpy()`-ing into un-iniitalized `char *` pointers, which is undefined behaviour. At the least you should be using `strdup()`, e.g. `m_make = strdup(make);`

Comment: @EJP: Thanks to the lack of the class definition, we don't actually know if they are `char*` or, say, `char[7]` members, so `strdup` might or might not be appropriate.

Comment: @ShadowRanger: pretty much everything works except for the make and model which leads me to believe that (letter = file.get()) != EOF works

Comment: @ShadowRanger Yes we do. He specifically states 'copy it into the `m_make` and `m_model char*`s'.

Comment: @BenNordin Honestly, you're being taught nonsense C++.  Even if you're being taught `C`, you don't write your own `strcpy`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: I mean, you might write your own `strcpy`, but it would be a standalone exercise for an introductory class that you then throw away in favor of the standard API for all future projects. You wouldn't build a complex program with nothing but the hacky crap you threw together, where not a single API call, no matter how simple, can be trusted to "just work".

Answer (score 1):

You are `strcpy()`-ing into un-initialized `char *` pointers, which is undefined behaviour.

At the least you should be using `strdup()`, e.g. `m_make = strdup(make);`, with a corresponding `free()` in the destructor.

Comment: I apologize, I have the string.h header in my program but I'm not allowed to use it.

Comment: @BenNordin Then you can't use `strcpy()` either. You previously only said that you can't use the `string` *class*. `strdup()` isn't part of that, and neither is `strcpy()`. If you can't use `strdup()`, use `malloc()` to allocate the required space and then your own string copy method. Or declare `m_make` and friends as char arrays of the required size, not forgetting room for a trailing null.

Comment: It turns out I was clearing the char*'s directly before I was printing them out in my readFile function

Comment: Nevertheless you still need to fix this stuff.